# Python - Total Cost

Tags: python

Statement: A cupcake costs A dollars and B cents. Determine, how many dollars and cents should one pay for N cupcakes. A program gets three numbers: A, B, N. It should print two numbers: total cost in dollars and cents.

I can't find the value of the cents.

```
import math
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
d=(a*c)
e=((b*c)/100)
f=math.floor(d+e)
print(f,)
```

Comment: Please add an example of your input and the bad output.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to work in cents alone. A cupcake that costs `A` dollars and `B` cents also costs `A*100 + B` cents.

```
dollars = int(input())
cents = int(input())
n = int(input())

# Convert to cents
cost = 100 * dollars + cents

total_cost = n * cost

# Convert back to dollars and cents
total_dollars, total_cents = divmod(total_cost, 100)
```

It's also safer. When doing arithmetic with currency, you don't want floating-point errors in intermediate totals to affect your result. Using integer arithmetic with whatever your smallest unit of currency is where possible.

Answer (score 0):

I find your choice of variable names a bit confusing. But if you simply want another variable `g` that outputs the number of cents in the total sales price on top of f (the number of whole dollars in the total sales price), then `g=int((d+e-f) * 100)` should work. You can then print `g` out.

Answer (score 0):

This code works exactly as you want:

```
import math
import math
a=int(input()) # dollars
b=int(input()) # cents
c=int(input()) # N

# Cost of one cupcake in cents. Note: 100 cents make a dollar
cost_in_cents = (a*100) + b

# Total cost of N cupcakes
total_cost = c * cost_in_cents

dollars = total_cost//100

cents = total_cost % 100

print(f"Total cost is {dollars} dollars and {cents} cents")
```

Comment: Just use `total_cost // 100` rather than truncating a floating-point value.

Comment: yes, of course. thanks